# SQL One to many relationships, duplicate/results being returned as unique rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, one-to-many

I have a database and some of the tables have one to many relationships. How do I eliminate the results being returned as its own unique row?

For instance I have a initiative table and a initiative can have many funding requirements. When I perform an inner join I'm getting the results but it looks like the rows are duplicating to output a unique value from the funding table.

[image: Results]

From the results, it should be like this

Row 3,4,5 should be in one row listing the results with the the funding required

```
Description | Acad_priority_1 | Acad_priority_2 | beginning_fiscal_year |
Develop...  |  false          | true            | 2018/2019             |
                                                | 2018/2019             |
                                                | 2019/2020
```

Can you please steer me in the right direction or show me how the SQL should be structured to achieve this?

SQL:

```
    SELECT plan_master.plan_id,
       plan_master.date_submitted,
       plan_master.filename,
       initiative_master.plan_id,
       initiative_master.NAME,
       initiative_master.acad_priority_1,
       funding.initiative_id,
       funding.beginning_fiscal_year
FROM   plan_master
       JOIN initiative_master
               ON plan_master.plan_id = initiative_master.plan_id
       JOIN funding
               ON initiative_master.initiative_id = funding.initiative_id  
ORDER BY Filename




|plan_id|date_submitted|filename|plan_id|NAME|acad_priority_1|initiative_id|begginning_fiscal_year|
|16F44FFE-5434-4E52-9D9A-F45C0A49D8E2|2018-12-03|1.txt|16F44FFE-5434-4E52-9D9A-F45C0A49D8E2|Space Utilization framework|false|8CCE0311-0E3C-467D-B675-04817A473056|2018/2019
|16F44FFE-5434-4E52-9D9A-F45C0A49D8E2|2018-12-03|1.txt|16F44FFE-5434-4E52-9D9A-F45C0A49D8E2|Space Utilization framework|false|8CCE0311-0E3C-467D-B675-04817A473056|2019/2020
|16F44FFE-5434-4E52-9D9A-F45C0A49D8E2|2018-12-03|1.txt|16F44FFE-5434-4E52-9D9A-F45C0A49D8E2|Space Utilization framework|false|8CCE0311-0E3C-467D-B675-04817A473056|2020/2021
```

Comment: Do you want to display the 3rd row(beginning_fiscal_year) as 2018/2020? And remove 4th, 5th ? As rest of the fields are identical

Comment: You have multiple rows and want one row to appear so you have to figure out how you pick which of the rows you want.   What makes you want the third row over the first two?

Comment: Learn to use alias.  Repeating long table names are annoying to read.

Comment: To achieve "_row 3 should list all the funding years_", you'll need more columns right? This is called a crosstab and there are many many examples of this online.

Comment: Images are hard to read.  Text is preferred.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I've updated how the result should be returned.

Comment: Based on that result, would you prefer to write a way to combine the ranges for the fiscal year to show the starting of the earliest and the ending of the latest (if they're consecutive) and show the results as either an average per year or a cumulative value?

Answer (score 0):

A simple join returns a cartesion product. If one table has 2 rows and another has 3, then there will be 6 rows of data. Need to do distinct on the data. You can do this:

```
SELECT plan.date_submitted,
   plan.filename,
   plan.department,
   plan.last_name,
   plan.first_name,
   plan.email,
   plan.mission_statement,
   plan.vision_statement,
   plan.goals_objectives,
   initiative.Name, 
   initiative.description,
   initiative.acad_priority_1,
   initiative.acad_priority_2,
   initiative.acad_priority_3,
   initiative.acad_priority_4,
   initiative.acad_priority_5,
   initiative.acad_priority_6
FROM plan_master as plan 
inner join (select distinct init.plan_id, init.NAME,
   init.description,
   init.acad_priority_1,
   init.acad_priority_2,
   init.acad_priority_3,
   init.acad_priority_4,
   init.acad_priority_5,
   init.acad_priority_6,
   init.operational_sustainability,
   init.people_plan,
   funding.beginning_fiscal_year from initiative_master as init
   join funding on funding.initiative_id = init.initiative_id ) as initiative  
    ON plan.plan_id = initiative.plan_id
ORDER BY Filename
```

Comment: Hi Guaravsa, yes that makes sense, I'm assuming this wasnt a copy/paste solution when I try to run the query I get.                                                                                          Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'plan'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: Getting the same results I'm attempting to figure out whats the issue. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'plan'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: When I copy the query into sql server tools there are 3 items that need attention. When I hover over plan "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'plan. Expecting ID or Quoted ID". Initiative shows "The column prefix 'initiative' does not with a table name or alias used in this query" and the as on the join shows "Incorrect syntax near 'as'

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'plan'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: No worries, still giving the same issue. Going to have to dedicate some time learning about distinct.

Comment: My apologies Guaravsa I was not thinking properly last night I believe the query would have worked the first time. I changed the alias from plan to pl and it ran successfully however it ends at acad_priority_1.

Comment: Need to add more fields in select query.. after initiative.acad_priority_1, add acad_priority2, and other fields. Please mark it as answer if it helped u. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 2 beginning fiscal year values cannot be combined into a single row unless you want to concatenate them with commas (or another separator), or write a function to show the value as a range, for example 2018-2020. You can however get rid of the 4th record using distinct or using the below mentioned over/partition by clauses.

If you don't mind, can you run the following query and provide the results that will help me identify the duplication issue:

```
SELECT plan_master.plan_id,
       plan_master.date_submitted,
       plan_master.filename,
       plan_master.department,
       plan_master.last_name,
       plan_master.first_name,
       plan_master.email,
       plan_master.mission_statement,
       plan_master.vision_statement,
       plan_master.goals_objectives,
       initiative_master.plan_id,
       initiative_master.NAME,
       initiative_master.description,
       initiative_master.acad_priority_1,
       initiative_master.acad_priority_2,
       initiative_master.acad_priority_3,
       initiative_master.acad_priority_4,
       initiative_master.acad_priority_5,
       initiative_master.acad_priority_6,
       initiative_master.operational_sustainability,
       initiative_master.people_plan,
       funding.initiative_id,
       funding.beginning_fiscal_year
FROM   plan_master
       JOIN initiative_master
               ON plan_master.plan_id = initiative_master.plan_id
       JOIN funding
               ON initiative_master.initiative_id = funding.initiative_id  
ORDER BY Filename
```

Once you get to the cause, you can either use a better join clause (multiple conditions), add a where clause, or use the [OVER clause in conjunction with the PARTITION BY clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax) to filter the data based on a ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Hi Yatin I shortened the query above and I provided the output above in the post.